# Minecraft Apple TV stuck on iCloud prompt

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-legacy-console

I have experienced multiple issues with the Apple TV port of Minecraft, which seems to be especially buggy and unstable. This is the latest, and it has completely prevented me from playing at all. On launch, it first prompts to enable a controller, (did that), then it prompts me with a "you need to be signed in to iCloud" message:

[image]

Select "Turn on iCloud" drops you in Minecraft detail view in settings. I get out of that, go to accounts and confirm I am signed in to iCloud, and return to Minecraft, but the screen remains.

I went so far as to sign out of iCloud, then back in, and return to Minecraft, but the prompt remained. I force-quit Minecraft and restarted it, and the prompt remained.

This seems to stem from another issue, where once your worlds use up too much space, they won't load. I experienced this with one world in which I covered a LOT of ground. It will no longer load. So I created a new world. I explored a fair amount of ground but not nearly as much this time. Then the game suddenly began to crash. Then this iCloud prompt issue.

I went and checked in settings to see how much space the game is taking up, and it is 197.1 MB. Very average, right in the middle of a long list of games installed on my Apple TV.

Is there any way out of this? Or are my worlds lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is because the CloudKit storage quota of 10 GB has been reached. Minecraft most likely uses this instead of local storage, and once it's full, you basically can't play the game anymore. This is a disappointing limitation of this platform.